# How to connect redux with react DOM nodes?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi is it possible to connect react dom nodes to store? I had few attempts like this:

```
import React, {DOM} from 'react';

export default connect((state,props) => {
  ...
})(DOM.a)
```

or this:

```
import React, {createFactory} from 'react';

export default connect((state,props) => {
  ...
})(createFactory('a'))
```

with no success. After while i currently solved this problem with this:

```
import React from 'react';

const anchor = (props) => {
  return <a {...props}>{props.children}</a>
}

export default connect((state, props) => {
  ...
})(anchor)
```

but I don't think it is needed.
Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: What is the root problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @Skay I'm build react app which is going to replace our old big app, for succesful transition between old and new app i need to add few query params to anchor tag href and i need to make it work across whole app without need to add something in definition because in future i want to just swap import of component on links which will be ported and get rid of these connects

Comment: So are you saying that you have an old app that puts data in anchor tag hrefs? And you want to rebuild those anchor links as React components and have your Redux app also populate the anchor tags with the same data?

Comment: Will anything outside of the React component or Redux app change the anchor tag? And if so, you want the Redux app to record those changes accordingly?

Comment: Old app is using few query params when navigating from page to page, which sometimes change after query to api, when i navigate to new app from old, i store first params in redux on server and build anchor tags, I have also connected middleware which handle change of params after request if needed and then i want to rebuild whole anchor tags with new data